# How do I achieve cell animation when it moves from one collectionView to another?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, uicollectionview

I have two collection views. One at the top and one at the bottom. On selecting a cell, I want to move it to the top collectionView by animating the cell just like this,

[image]

I can add and delete cells in a conventional way. But can anyone tell me an approach to follow specifically for this animation?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way. But still suggestions are welcome. I am taking a step by step approach to achieve this animation in didSelectRow.

1. Populate destination collectionView datasource and insert new item (Keep it hidden for now.)
2. Duplicate the selected collectionViewCell and store it in a variable, dummyView.
3. Make the collectionViewCell background to grey and hide the textLabel.
4. Add the duplicated dummyView onto the same frame(w.r.t. self.view) as the collectionViewCell.
5. Animate it to move to the destination cell.
6. Unhide the original destination cell and remove dummyView from the superView.

Hope anyone reading this will understand. Feel free to put a comment if not :)